# Pointing SquidGuard Squid proxy for realtime url reputation or category check

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

I am trying to use Sophos Intelix for url category checking or for filtering through squid proxy. Also caching a result locally on the proxy (for a specific duration) until url is checked again. 
I am using Intelix for some time in other custom apps and it works well. I am looking for some help with setting up Sophos Intelix integration with squid. Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Chuck Star, please could you provide some details of how you are currently integrating Intelix into Squid and what issues you are seeing?